# iPhone - Best way to store data for my app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, data-structures

i want to create a application with stores some categories and some items inside the categories.
I decided to create a Class for a categories and a class for items.
My thought was to create a object of the categories class, and put the object inside an array. Like:

```
CategoryNSObject *category = [[CategoryNSObject alloc] init];
[aCategoriesArray addObject:category];
```

Inside the category object i created another array which should store the items.

I have a UITableView where i can create the categories (which is already working). And then i want if some categories are created and i tap on one of the categories, another tableview should appear, where i can create the items for the category. But here is the point where i stuck.

Is this the easiest/best way to do it??
Can someone help me?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

i found a solution: Add an array inside a object. the array inside a objects also holds objects. Works for me.

Comment: It is better to take NSMutableDictionary and try to load the NSMutableArray objects in the dictionary

Comment: Wish there was a way to reduce the 'close' votes - nothing wrong with this question and sometimes it feels like it is just people testing out their new stack overflow tools...

Answer (score 2):

When you say store - I'm assuming you mean persist permanently even after the application has been closed.  In that case - Core Data is ideal for persistence and storing these items in relation to their categories.  This is not an easy thing to implement but I would suggest starting with the Xcode Master/Detail template project and referencing https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html

IF you are only looking to store these objects for the application's duration - you can go a simpler approach by having everything stored as NSObjects.  I'd also recommend creating a model controller (maybe even a singleton) that can keep these categories and their items alive for the duration of application.  That way, your data won't be lost when a view controller is destroyed.

In addition, you can point your table view's data source to this model controller to keep the UIViewController's code clean and reusable.